# ¿Cómo cargar la imagen de perfil de facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook-api

Necesito la imagen de perfil de usuario de facebook, el nombre y los apellidos los consigo pero al intentar coger la imagen me da error:

```
public void cargarImagenPerfil(){
    URL imageUrl = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try{
            imageUrl = new URL(prefs.getString(IMAGEN, ""));
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;

            Bitmap imagen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream(), new Rect(0,0,0,0), options);
            imagePerfil.setImageBitmap(imagen);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Da este error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host: https://
>   graph.facebook.com/id/picture?width=200&height=200

Comment: ¿La url que estás usando la has escrito bien?. En el mensaje de error que pones hay un espacio entre "https://" y "graph".

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la cadena con la URL de la imagen (`IMAGEN`)?¿Cómo se genera? Parece que falta código en la pregunta para poder ver el problema completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en la URL que estás invocando. Fíjate que en el mensaje de error que pones hay un espacio entre "https://" y "graph". Por lo que la URL no es válida y se lanza la excepción.